# I'd like to search something on a searching engine with java

Tags: java, search

like on google for example I'd like my program to ask me for what I want to search on google I type what I want to search and my program search it on google for example.
Do I have to use Jsoup? Could I use something else?

Comment: ironically, you can find the answer to your question by using Google...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the google [custom search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) 
The free edition is limited to the first 100 results.

It is also possible to use jsoup, but a layout/css change on the website breaking the selectors is more likely than a change in the cs API, so using the API is more stable. Also an unusual amount of searches from one ip might get the ip blocked (just a speculation), but if your application will just pass manual searches from the user, this should not be a problem.

jsoup approach:

```
String searchTerm = "jsoup examples";
int numberOfResultpages = 5;
String searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+searchTerm.replace(" ", "+")+"&start=";

Document doc;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResultpages; i++) {

    doc = Jsoup.connect(searchUrl+i).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36")
              .referrer("https://www.google.com/").get(); // note: not working without userAgent

    for (Element result : doc.select("h3.r a")) 
    {
        String title = result.text();
        String url = result.attr("href");

        // just printing out title and link to demonstate the approach
        System.out.println(title + " -> " + url);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Example program: list links: jsoup Java HTML parser -> https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links
Extract attributes, text, and HTML from elements: jsoup Java HTML ... -> https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html
Use selector-syntax to find elements: jsoup Java HTML parser -> https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax
...
```